# URL is not getting loaded when I try to send value from JavaScript to PHP with ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I use

```
if(isset($_POST['category_drop'])){
    var_dump($_POST );
    echo $_POST['category_drop'];
}  {...} to check for the post condition in PHP.
```

Kindly provide me a solution.

```
$('.category_filter .dropdown-menu li a ').on('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var category = $(this).text();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'page_author.php',
        data: {
            category_drop: category
        },
        success: function(data) {
            // do something;
            alert(category);
        }
    });
});
```

---

I am getting this below value in an alert box , but my page is not getting loaded with the respective value,

> array(1) {   ["category_drop"]=>   string(12) "Accomodation" }

Accomodation

Comment: Kindly edit your question... It is not readable....

Comment: remove `var_dump($_POST );`

Comment: @RamRaider I removed and tried but still I only get the alert statement only, page_author.php is not populated with those POST values.

Answer (score 1):

> The commented Code below shows how you may accomplish your goal:

```
    e.preventDefault();
    var category = $(this).text();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'page_author.php',
        data: {
            category_drop: category
        },
        success: function(data) {
            // PERHAPS IT'S NOT category BUT data THAT YOU SHOULD BE INTERESTED IN.
            // AND; YOU BETTER console.log() 
            // TO AVOID THOSE ANNOYING JAVASCRIPT ALERTS...
            // ALTHOUGH, YOU MAY STILL ALERT THE category IF YOU WISHED...
            console.log(data);
            //alert(category);
        }
    });
```

**ON THE PHP SIDE OF THINGS:**

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['category_drop'])){
        // ASSIGN THE $_POST['category_drop'] TO A VARIABLE $categoryDrop
        // TO BE USED IN YOUR MySQL DATABASE QUERIES...
        $categoryDrop = $_POST['category_drop'];

        // YOU CAN NOW USE $categoryDrop IN YOUR MySQL QUERIES.
        // AFTERWARDS, IF YOU WANT TO ONLY SEND BACK THE $categoryDrop
        // YOU CAN SIMPLY DO:
        //EITHER:
        die($categoryDrop);

    }
```

Comment: page_author.php is not being populated with both the statements  echo $_POST['category_drop'];

        // OR           
        die( json_encode($_POST));

Comment: what does the fn console.log(data) does ?? can you explain??

Comment: @Praveenkumar `console.log()` works like `alert()` but does not pop-up any annoying Windows and it gives you fine-grained representation of your Data. You can view the Results of `console.log()` from the `Console` Tab of your Browser's Web-Developer Panel.

Comment: @Praveenkumar    And additionally;  with the Code up there, nothing is expected to be Populated because the Response was not bound to any "DOM" Element. You can only view the Result in the Web-Browsers Console. If you want to populate any DOM Element with the Response, you'd need to explicitly do that in the Success Handler of your AJAX Script like: `$("div.response-box").text(data)`. But to do that also, your Data should be String: Not JSON. So you need to remove `die(json_encode($_POST))` from your PHP Code

Comment: Thanks for your info ..But I am in need of "$_POST['category_drop'] "value for fetching records from mysql.. So for that also do I need to make the change that you mentioned.

Comment: @Praveenkumar  The Code has been modified to only cater for `$_POST['category_drop']`... Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

PHP:

```
 $result = array(
 'success' => false,
 );
 if(isset($_POST['category_drop'])){
    $result['category'] = $_POST['category_drop'];
    $result['success'] = true;
    // you can pass in result array whatever you need
 }
echo json_encode($result);
exit;
```

Js:

```
$('.category_filter .dropdown-menu li a ').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var category = $(this).text();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'page_author.php',
    dataType: 'application/json',
    data: {
        category_drop: category
    },
    success: function(data) {
       if(data.success){
        //do something here   
        console.log(data.category);
        console.log(data);
        }
    }
 });
});
```

Always use good practices :)

Comment: When you already have category name with you before ajax call, why you need to call ajax to get same category value?

Comment: I used an error:function(data){alert("error");} ... It alerts error so I think there is something wrong with the above ajax query

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your question you may follow this.

### PHP

```
     $result = array(
        'category' => null,
        'success' => false
    );
    if (isset($_POST['category_drop'])) {
        $result['category'] = $_POST['category_drop'];
        $result['success'] = true;
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
    exit;
```

### JS

```
        $('.category_filter .dropdown-menu li a ').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var category = $(this).text();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'page_author.php',
                dataType: 'application/json',
                data: {
                    category_drop: category
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                       // append here the category value
                       // to your respective TAG
                       $("YOUR-RESPECTIVE TAG").text(data.category);

                       //OR

                       $("YOUR-RESPECTIVE TAG").text(data['category']);   

                    }
                }
            });
        });
```